# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation

Tags: android, kotlin, illegalstateexception, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying the new Jetpack compose but when I switch to `kapt`, I get this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation`.

It works fine with annotationProcessor, but I want to use kapt for this project. I would appreciate any help with this.

I understand that a lot of issues can lead to such error as above but I think that this one is peculiar to `jetpack` and `kapt`

I have added my `.gradle` file below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.jerryhanks.pinchme"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

//        javaCompileOptions {
//            annotationProcessorOptions {
//                arguments = [
//                        "room.schemaLocation":"$projectDir/schemas".toString(),
//                        "room.incremental":"true",
//                        "room.expandProjection":"true"]
//            }
//        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

// To inline the bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into
// bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. (e.g. navArgs)


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'

    /**Compose*/
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev02'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev02'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev02'

    /**Corountine*/
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$versions.coroutine"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$versions.coroutine"
//    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:$versions.coroutine"

    /**Room*/
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$versions.room"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$versions.room"

    /**Test*/
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$versions.room"

    /**Android Test*/
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: post your gradle file please

Comment: I have added my .gradle file.

Comment: I wrote this as an answer but it was deleted because it did "not provide an answer to the question" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯: Compose and Room are currently incompatible due to this bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34583

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-34583) that the team is still working on.

> Compose is still experimental and should not be used in a production application. Furthermore, Compose requires enabling the new/experimental IR (Intermediate Representation) backend to the Kotlin compiler, so you will likely encounter language bugs related to the new backend.

Compose does require IR backend (with Google extensions).

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have been resolved in the more recent builds of compose. Try 1.0.0beta08